# Nested v-for loops and incorrect data placement

Tags: javascript, sorting, vue.js, vuejs2

I got some complex (ugly!) data from a backend API (JSON) and I am trying to display it correctly in an HTML table. There are ordered list items that are not in their correct slots in the table.

For example, notice in the screenshot how the `2.1, 2.2`, etc items are placed under the `1.`. It should be moved down one slot to their respective numbered list. I understand that the data from the API is incorrect also. I am looking for a presentational fix to this.

[image]

Any ideas how to fix?

```
<template>
<div>

  <table>
    <!-- <tr v-if='eg[0].type == "ExREF"'> -->
      <tr>
      <th>General:</th>
      <td>
        <ol><li v-for='(item, index) in eg' v-if='item.type == "ExREF"' :key='index'>{{item["General Considerations Guidance"]}}</li></ol>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Considerations:</th>
      <td>
        <ol>
          <li v-for='(item, index) in eg' v-if='item.type == "Extract"' :key='index'>
            {{item["General Considerations Guidance"]}}
            <ol>
              <li v-for='(a, index) in item.Nodes' :key='index' type='a'>
                <em>{{a.Node}}</em> {{a["General Considerations Guidance"]}}
                  <ol>
                    <li v-for='(i, index) in a.Nodes' :key='index' type='i'>
                      <em>{{i.Node}}</em>{{i["General Considerations Guidance"]}}
                    </li>
                  </ol>
              </li>
            </ol>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
</template>
```

Comment: Array index shouldn't be used as :key value, because you can't guarantee that it will be unique and always associated with one specific item. As for your data, you would have to create a computed property that deep filters your data array and moves proper subarray to the correct object.

Comment: Thanks. Hoping someone can help me with the deep filter

Comment: do i understand correctly, that you are asking for code that would re-format the structure that the api gives you into something that has the proper children for each node?

Comment: @phoet. Aside from actually chagning the backend api code, I am open to any ideas on how we can visually get the sub list order correct on the front-end.

Comment: It looks to me like the data is displaying exactly how its formatted on the backend. For example if you look at the data in the gist link you posted, nodes 2.1 and 2.2 are children of node 1..

Comment: @DerekFulginiti Yes but although the data is formatted like that, it is incorrect. I am simply trying to do a dirty fix on the front end. Salvage, if you will. The nodes 2.1 and 2.2 should be under the 2. section.

Comment: what did you try to re-structure the data?

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with vue - fix dataset in fetch's (or whatever API you're using) callback, not template

Comment: If you want to "fix" this in the front end, just use a computed property that returns the correctly ordered structure, and reference that computed property instead of `eg` in the template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort the text-heading nodes as follows:

1. **flatten nodes** - ungroups all nodes so that they're all at the same depth, which facilitates sorting
2. **sort nodes** - sorts the nodes by type and heading number
3. **group nodes** - given a sorted list, groups together nodes under the appropriate heading

Then, use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) (e.g., named "egSorted") to return the input (`eg`) sorted:

```
import { sortNodes } from './tree.js';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      eg: [...]
    };
  },
  computed: {
    egSorted() {
      return sortNodes(this.eg);
    }
  }
}
```

And in your template, replace `eg` with `egSorted`.

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/887r91rom2?module=src/components/ExtractionGuidance.vue)